# HLSL pixel shader for white balance/color temperature?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, shader, hlsl

Anyone got HLSL code for a pixel shader to apply color temperature to an image?

I'd like to apply a temperature in Kelvin to an image, but my limited grasp of mathematics is holding me back a bit. I found a bit of code in Visual Basic which I converted to HLSL, but I think the pow() function in the HLSL is not working right with negative values.

I've been battling away at this for a bit, and rather than unsuccessfully re-invent the wheel, anyone got some HLSL?

Comment: Try [this page](https://mouaif.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/photoshop-math-with-glsl-shaders/). It has a link to some code.

Comment: This may be a good reference: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsSXW1

Comment: This at shadertoy is precisely what I'm after, and it works great once converted to HLSL PS 3.0, but unfortunately will not build for PS 2.0 as it exceeds 64 arithmetic slots. Almost perfect though.